# Using `BTM` with `predict` in R is outputting uniform topic probabilities of 0.1

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I have a 3000 x 2 corpus data frame whose name is `dfcorpus`, comprised of two columns: document ids and texts (lowercased and preprocessed). I am using the biterm topic model `BTM` package in `R` as follows:

```
library(BTM)

> model = BTM(data = dfcorpus,
              k = 10,
              detailed = TRUE,
              trace = TRUE)

> model
Biterm Topic Model
  trained with 1000 Gibbs iterations, alpha: 5, beta: 0.01
  topics: 10
  size of the token vocabulary: 29768
  topic distribution theta: 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
```

As you see, the topic distribution is straight 0.1s. This is also cascaded to the inference outputs of all the documents:

```
> head(predict(model, newdata = dfcorpus))
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1   0.1
2  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1   0.1
3  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1   0.1
4  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1   0.1
5  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1   0.1
6  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1   0.1
```

One would expect that it is because of the data that theta is 0.1s. However, I used the [original `C++` implementation](https://github.com/xiaohuiyan/BTM) instead of the `R` wrapper and I got different more versatile probabilities. I also followed the examples in the documentation of [`BTM`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BTM/versions/0.3.1/topics/BTM) and was able to get versatile probabilities. This hints that the problem lies in my `R` implementation, so I want to know what the problem with my implementation is.

---

**EDIT**

The data I am using when observing the odd behaviour are the mock data provided [here](https://github.com/xiaohuiyan/BTM/tree/master/sample-data).

As to the example I followed and got versatile probabilities, I list it next ([source](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BTM/versions/0.3.1/topics/BTM)):

```
> library(udpipe)
> library(BTM)
> data("brussels_reviews_anno", package = "udpipe")
> x <- subset(brussels_reviews_anno, language == "nl")
> x <- subset(x, xpos %in% c("NN", "NNP", "NNS"))
> x <- x[, c("doc_id", "lemma")]
> model  <- BTM(x, k = 5, alpha = 1, beta = 0.01, iter = 10, trace = TRUE)
2020-07-29 11:41:04 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 1/10
2020-07-29 11:41:04 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 2/10
2020-07-29 11:41:04 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 3/10
2020-07-29 11:41:04 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 4/10
2020-07-29 11:41:05 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 5/10
2020-07-29 11:41:05 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 6/10
2020-07-29 11:41:05 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 7/10
2020-07-29 11:41:05 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 8/10
2020-07-29 11:41:05 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 9/10
2020-07-29 11:41:05 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 10/10
> model
Biterm Topic Model
  trained with 10 Gibbs iterations, alpha: 1, beta: 0.01
  topics: 5
  size of the token vocabulary: 1667
  topic distribution theta: 0.202 0.208 0.221 0.189 0.179
```

Note the topic distribution probabilities. Now inferring $p(z|d)$:

```
> head(predict(model, newdata = x))
               [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
10185723 0.18745036 0.23528461 0.17010275 0.18650434 0.22065795
10284782 0.03442299 0.22308442 0.37919379 0.18913706 0.17416174
10597787 0.11599689 0.13501897 0.09783666 0.58588106 0.06526642
10789408 0.14422460 0.45259918 0.16515674 0.10697039 0.13104909
10809161 0.15523735 0.06510719 0.48236257 0.26374167 0.03355122
10913343 0.06599192 0.15961549 0.46651229 0.06327143 0.24460886
```

Comment: Why not put the examples followed in `BTM` with the results derived that were versatile. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dfcorpus should be a tokenised data.frame as indicated in the help of BTM at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTM/BTM.pdf

```r
## Get your data - 1 row per document
x <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xiaohuiyan/BTM/master/sample-data/doc_info.txt")
x <- data.frame(doc_id = 1:length(x), text = x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
nrow(x)
#> [1] 30000
## Tokenise text - split by space to get 1 row per token - see help of the BTM function: ?BTM
library(udpipe)
dfcorpus <- strsplit.data.frame(x, term = "text", group = "doc_id", split = " ")
nrow(dfcorpus)
#> [1] 148245
head(dfcorpus, n = 10)
#>    doc_id      text
#> 1       1      ipod
#> 2       1    tumblr
#> 3       1       app
#> 4       1   working
#> 5       1      fine
#> 6       2       yup
#> 7       2    longer
#> 8       3    jungle
#> 9       3 abduction
#> 10      3     alive
## Build the model - using iter 20 to quickly show something but you should normally take 1000/2000 Gibbs iterations
library(BTM)
model <- BTM(data = dfcorpus, k = 10, detailed = TRUE, iter = 20, trace = 10)
#> 2020-07-29 20:20:08 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 1/20
#> 2020-07-29 20:20:16 Start Gibbs sampling iteration 11/20
model
#> Biterm Topic Model
#>   trained with 20 Gibbs iterations, alpha: 5, beta: 0.01
#>   topics: 10
#>   size of the token vocabulary: 28634
#>   topic distribution theta: 0.075 0.11 0.116 0.13 0.13 0.08 0.087 0.089 0.075 0.107
## Use predict and show some
scores <- predict(model, newdata = dfcorpus)
head(scores, n = 5)
#>           [,1]        [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]
#> 1 2.682796e-02 0.016116481 8.207263e-02 4.334003e-01 2.908850e-01 1.805332e-02
#> 2 3.566287e-05 0.191604268 9.500306e-05 4.715159e-01 2.077098e-08 3.379564e-08
#> 3 1.312881e-01 0.003985054 1.152026e-02 7.568868e-03 4.480935e-01 1.140198e-04
#> 4 1.315275e-07 0.029871326 5.941080e-06 7.688591e-08 7.668167e-08 2.859951e-05
#> 5 5.525665e-02 0.001815486 3.407789e-03 6.540897e-01 5.049276e-03 2.669286e-03
#>           [,7]         [,8]         [,9]      [,10]
#> 1 2.829724e-06 2.375107e-03 9.312936e-02 0.03713697
#> 2 3.089975e-08 9.064206e-06 1.156608e-01 0.22107922
#> 3 8.330137e-04 3.289586e-01 3.613660e-03 0.06402498
#> 4 2.354538e-05 9.512406e-01 1.320487e-07 0.01882959
#> 5 7.635004e-07 6.455946e-02 1.450137e-02 0.19865020
## Plot the model
library(textplot)
library(ggraph)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(concaveman)
plot(model)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You should probably also limit the words in the model by frequency or by selecting only certain parts of speech tags (e.g. with the udpipe R package) to limit the words in the model to the most meaningfull ones to get sensible topics.

Comment: The `C++` implementation biased me a bit towards inputting the same data in the `R` wrapper. Indeed this works, appreciated.